# Add playlist object to my JWPlayer

Tags: thumbnails, jwplayer

I try to add the playlist object (to display the thumbnails) to my JWPlayer, but it doesn't work (player disappear). Any idea ? I tried to combine my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="-";</script>
<div id="player_div" style="outline:0px;">Loading...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var playerInstance = jwplayer("player_div");
        playerInstance.setup({
        autostart: "0",
        startparam: "start",
        aspectratio: "12:7",
        width: "100%",
        image: "/content/img/mp4-poster.jpg",
        sources: [{
            file: "<?= getsignedurl('http://videos.-.land/480/'.$object, time() + 3600) ?>",
            type: "mp4",
            },{
            file: "<?= getsignedurl('http://videos.-.land/720/'.$object, time() + 3600) ?>",
            type: "mp4",
            "default": true,
        }]
    });
</script>
```

To it

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    playlist: [{
        file: "/assets/myVideo.mp4",
        image: "/assets/myPoster.jpg",
        tracks: [{ 
            file: "/assets/myThumbnails.vtt", 
            kind: "thumbnails"
        }]
    }]
});
```